# Why the script file is on my req.params how to get rid of that?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to extract the :rid to my req.params but I get two values the rid and the script file.

here is the console.log picture

[console.log picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFEhA.png)

**my route code**

```
router.get('/room/:rid', async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.params);
  res.render('room', { roomId: req.params.rid });
});
```

my dashboard code to redirect the user to room.ejs when the user click

```
 function goto(){
    var roomID = document.getElementById("roomID").value;

    window.location.replace(`/room/${roomID}`);

 }
```

and my room.ejs head

```
<script src="this.js" defer></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
<script src="this.js" defer></script>
```

to this:

```
<script src="/this.js" defer></script>
```

Assuming that script was present in a web page called `/room`, then when the browser sees a request for `"this.js"`, it will combine that with the path of the page and ask for `/room/this.js` which will hit your `/room/:rid` route which is not what you want.

Generally, you always want script file paths to be absolute paths (start with a `/`) so they are fixed and not dependent upon the path  of the page they are contained in .